# JSONLint says valid JSON but I cannot grab values from it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I am trying to parse a JSON from a GET request in JavaScript. I can run it through JSONLint and other tools and it's fine. If I copy/paste the exact result into the JavaScript I can access the values from the object as well.

Here is a shortened example of what the JSON structure looks like:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "EXAMPLE.com/$metadata#EXAMPLE.results",
    "value": [{
        "SerialNo_Company": "1",
        "Calculated_AsBuilt": "AsBuilt",
        "SerialNo_SerialNumber": "1",
        "SerialNo_PartNum": "2A",
        "JobHead_RevisionNum": "A",
        "JobMtl_MtlSeq": 30,
        "JobMtl_PartNum": "A123",
        "JobMtl_RevisionNum": "A",
        "JobMtl_Description": "KEY",
        "JobMtl_QtyPer": "1.00000000",
        "JobMtl_IUM": "EA",
        "JobHead_JobNum": "13",
        "JobMtl_IssuedQty": "2.00000000",
        "JobMtl_RequiredQty": "2.00000000",
        "RowIdent": "7e91b43a-897c-49b4-b68f-307b9ba74832"
    }, {
        "SerialNo_Company": "1",
        "Calculated_AsBuilt": "AsBuilt",
        "SerialNo_SerialNumber": "1",
        "SerialNo_PartNum": "2A",
        "JobHead_RevisionNum": "A",
        "JobMtl_MtlSeq": 30,
        "JobMtl_PartNum": "A123",
        "JobMtl_RevisionNum": "A",
        "JobMtl_Description": "KEY",
        "JobMtl_QtyPer": "1.00000000",
        "JobMtl_IUM": "EA",
        "JobHead_JobNum": "14",
        "JobMtl_IssuedQty": "2.00000000",
        "JobMtl_RequiredQty": "2.00000000",
        "RowIdent": "6251fbaf-36d0-4fcf-b65a-9dde70ffb13d"  
    }]
}
```

This format isn't entirely correct though, what it actually outputs has a structure like so:

```
"{\r\n  \"odata.metadata\":\"EXAMPLE.com/$metadata#Example.results\",\"value\":[\r\n    {\r\n      \"SerialNo_Company\":\"1\",\"Calculated_AsBuilt\":\"AsBuilt\",\"SerialNo_SerialNumber\":\"1\",\"SerialNo_PartNum\":\"2A\",\"JobHead_RevisionNum\":\"A\",\"JobMtl_MtlSeq\":30,\"JobMtl_PartNum\":\"A13518N-28-KS\",\"JobMtl_RevisionNum\":\"A\",\"JobMtl_Description\":\"KEY\",\"JobMtl_QtyPer\":\"1.00000000\",\"JobMtl_IUM\":\"EA\",\"JobHead_JobNum\":\"13\",\"JobMtl_IssuedQty\":\"2.00000000\",\"JobMtl_RequiredQty\":\"2.00000000\",\"RowIdent\":\"111531e1-f4da-4d2d-b980-0074227a474e\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}
```

When I try to query the first structure when hard coded in javascript, for example

```
object.value[0]
```

I get the first value and all is good.

The second one does not return a value with the same query. I removed the `\r\n` and it did not work. Also, `JSON.stringify()` puts in a bunch of backslashes in the structure and I don't know why.

Thanks for reading if you made it this far, please help.

Comment: `""SerialNo_Company": "1",` is invalid in the JSON you pasted above, it should start with one double quote, not two.

Comment: sorry for that mistake. I fixed it here. I found i can get it working if i replace all the \r\n and \" values with just " but some of my content has \" inside of it, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I pasted your JSON above in the console and ran `JSON.stringify` on it and it did not add any special characters, so I am not sure why it's doing that for you.

Comment: Looks like something's double-encoding it... Show the code where you make the request to get the data, and where you're logging that shows the second code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the output in my node.js app. I was using res.json() and it was double-encoding the response. The output resulted in a javascript readable format from there. Thanks to Heretic Monkey for the answer